# Is it safe to send ODATA rest batch requests in HTTPS Body via POST and get response in the same

Tags: rest, security, odata, sap-successfactors

We are planning use below rest request for SAP-Successfactor,  which send bulk request at a time in Body

Please find Example below :

**OData API POST Request :** https://<>/odata/v2/$batch

**Body Start :**

```
--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET getUsersByDynamicGroup?groupId=6119L&$format=json HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET getUsersByDynamicGroup?groupId=6000L&$format=json HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET getUsersByDynamicGroup?groupId=1588L&$format=json HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET getUsersByDynamicGroup?groupId=1234L&$format=json HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET getUsersByDynamicGroup?groupId=123L&$format=json HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b--
```

**Body End :**

**Response in Body :**

```
--batch_c96b193b-b98c-4a4b-b479-696536f72239
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
DataServiceVersion: 1.0
Content-Length: 133

{
"d" : [
{
"firstName" : "Automation", "lastName" : "User9", "middleName" : "Test", "userId" : "103272", "userName" : "103272"
}
]
}

--batch_c96b193b-b98c-4a4b-b479-696536f72239
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
DataServiceVersion: 1.0
Content-Length: 127

{
"d" : [
{
"firstName" : "Ava", "lastName" : "Johnston", "middleName" : null, "userId" : "ajohnston", "userName" : "Ava"
}
]
}
```

When we send request in Post, I know its secure
but still I was just thinking is safe to do all this ?

Please ignore me I am asking some basic question .

Please enlighten me if you have something to share regarding this.

Comment: Not sure what your question is? Maybe you enlight me first

Comment: "Safe" in which regard? This question is too broad without specifying what the question is about. Consider to ask in https://security.stackexchange.com/ instead with more information.